# Best approach when no Internet connection - RevMob ads

Tags: flash, air, revmob

I have an adobe air application, running on both IOS and android platforms. I have managed to implement the banner and the awarded video ad. Whenever the user disconnects from wifi or 3G/LTE the banner normally won't show up, and neither the awarded video. 
 My question is, what is the best approach to handle this situation ? : 
- Should i force the user to have an internet connection while playing the game? would this affect the user experience 
 
- Since i am in adobe flash CS6,  how can i prevent the app from running if there is no connection? ( if it turned out that the best solution is to force internet connection) 
- Should i just hope that he doesn't disconnect from any internet source? in order to make some money!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Elias](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1503394/elias-rahme),

Answering your questions in order:

- I believe that forcing users to play the game only when having an internet connection is **not** a good choice. Because it's better to have an user not monetizing that having no users at all. Unless your game has some sort of p2p feature, in that case you should block users with no internet connection
- To check if the user has an internet connection you can follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13569775/5128351)
- Revmob's ads are pretty light to download, so you will hardly get in a situation that users won't see ads because of internet connections. To avoid this it's important to load the ad on app start so there is plenty of time for the ad to be loaded

Comment: Thank You! always the best answers!